# Pivot data or use crosstab - pivot one column in my table in order to get desired solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, ssms

I am trying to pivot a dataset using SQL Server. I have not found a method on how to do this. I need help in solving this issue. Below is how the data looks right now.

[image]

This is the transformation I need in order to solve my problem. Which is pivoting the attribution column and creating a Y flag where the attribution logic is met. Thank you for your help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIVOT together with IIF (similar to CASE) for arriving at result set

```sql
DECLARE @patient table(patientNumber int, physician varchar(20), Attribution varchar(30))

insert into @patient
values
(1234 ,'Jim','Consulting'  ),
(1234 ,'seth','Consulting' ),
(1234 ,'john','Referring'  ),
(2345 ,'sally','Attending' ),
(4567 ,'James','Admitting' ),
(3424 ,'jack','Admitting'  ),
(5678 ,'sally','Admitting' ),
(5678 ,'Mike','Consulting' );

SELECT patientNumber, physician, 
iif(consulting = 1, 'Y','') as consulting,
iif(Referring = 1, 'Y','') as Referring,
iif(Attending = 1, 'Y','') as Attending,
iif(Admitting = 1, 'Y','') as Admitting
FROM @patient
PIVOT
(
COUNT(Attribution) for attribution in ([Consulting],[Referring],[Attending],[Admitting])
) as pvt
```

One more option available using CROSS APPLY

```sql
SELECT patientNumber, physician, t.* 
FROM @patient as p
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT 
iif(p.Attribution = 'Consulting','Y','') AS Consulting,
iif(p.Attribution = 'Referring', 'Y','') as Referring,
iif(p.Attribution = 'Attending', 'Y','') as Attending,
iif(p.Attribution = 'Admitting', 'Y','') as Admitting
) as t
```

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| patientNumber | physician | consulting | Referring | Attending | Admitting |
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          3424 | jack      |            |           |           | Y         |
|          4567 | James     |            |           |           | Y         |
|          1234 | Jim       | Y          |           |           |           |
|          1234 | john      |            | Y         |           |           |
|          5678 | Mike      | Y          |           |           |           |
|          2345 | sally     |            |           | Y         |           |
|          5678 | sally     |            |           |           | Y         |
|          1234 | seth      | Y          |           |           |           |
+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    PatientNumber,
    Physician,
    max(case when Attribution = 'Consulting' then 'Y' end) Consulting,
    max(case when Attribution = 'Attending'  then 'Y' end) Attending,
    max(case when Attribution = 'Admitting'  then 'Y' end) Admitting
from mytable 
group by PatientNumber, Physician
order by PatientNumber, Physician
```